# Jasperreports: line under each row

Tags: jasper-reports, textfield, multiline

I have a rather long String as an input in my report. It is desirable to represent it in a such way that every next line of this String is underlined.

Usage of style "underlined" doesn't help since it underlines words only and I want thewhole line to be underlined.
Using border doesn't do the trick as well since it shows one line only at the very bottom of the textfield.

Will be greatful for any help here.

P.S. Sorry for the excessive usage of word "line" here :)

Comment: You can the *line* element or use the border of *textFields*. You can look at [Adding table border in jasperreports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10278067/876298) post

Comment: You can also look at this posts: [Conditional Horizontal line in jasperreport between results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16568499/876298) & [JasperReports: Show line between two enteries, but not after the last record](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18339215/876298)

Comment: All these solutions don't apply for my case, since I don't have a table or an array of data, I just have one very long String field.
And if I use a line element, or a border for the textField it will appear only once, but I need it for every line of my multiline textField.